# Smallest eigenvalue of a positive matrix in expectation form

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, convex-optimization

Let a distribution $D$ over $\mathbb{R}^d$ and a sequence of datapoints $X_n=(x_1, x_2,\dots x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ which are i.i.d drawn from $D$ be given.

Suppose we have
$$\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D} [x x^T]\succeq \alpha I \iff \sigma_{\min}(\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D} [x x^T])\ge \alpha$$
where $\succeq$ means the ordering of symmetric matrices and $\sigma_{\min}$ is the smallest eigenvalue.

My question is that if we can say anything to the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X_n^TX_n}{n}\right]$, is it still no less than $\alpha$? My first impression is that this is true because of the i.i.d settings, but I just don't know how to give a rigorous proof.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have zero mean for the distribution D?

Comment: @KBS I guess not, $D$ can be any distribution. I am not sure if zero mean will help here.

Comment: @NalRa It can as the OP has a typo in the dimensions of $X_n$ or in $X_n^TX_n$. Depending on that, we can have $X_n^TX_n=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T$ or it can be $X_n^TX_n=[x_ix_j^T]_{i,j}$. In the latter case, that would be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X_{n}^{\top}X_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{i}^{\top}$, therefore you have
$$\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
\mathbb{E}\biggl[\frac{X_{n}^{\top}X_{n}}{n}\biggr]&=\mathbb{E}\biggl[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{i}^{\top}\biggr]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[x_{i}x_{i}^{\top}] & \text{by independent}\\
&=\frac{1}{\cancel{n}}\cancel{n}\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[xx^{\top}] &\text{by identical distributed}.
\end{align*}$$